Battery optimization with macOS Sequoia 15.0
I am using macOS Sequoia 15.0. 24A335, laptop Macbook pro m1 2000
If the battery optimization option is enabled and there is a change in the battery charge (0.1%), the battery charges to 100% and then resets the charge to 80%.
If the battery optimization option is disabled, when the charge changes (0.1%), the battery discharges to 80% and then charges to 100%.
The problem appeared or I saw it after updating macOS.
How to fix?

Can you clarify what you mean when you say the charge "resets"? What is the patch of build level of MacOS 15? What is your laptop (?) model and how old is it? When did these issues first begin?

Please put all that info in the main question body to help make it more clear. Use the EDIT button to do this.
